# Solving trig equation on both sides for finding angle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, trigonometry

I'm reading "On Packing Squares with Equal Squares" [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316575900990) . Just for fun/practice I've been trying to find the angle of incline of the rectangles formed by the $\alpha - N+1$ unit squares displayed below. Here's what I've worked out so far:

[[image: <span class=]$\beta = \alpha-N$, small squares are unit squares" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgpqj.png)

[image: My work]

It seems I can't find a u value regardless of $\alpha$ and $N$. In particular, it's not working for the $\alpha = 1000000.01$ and $N=1000000$ proposed in the paper and I'm wondering if I'm making some sort of mistake or if there's something I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from @Glärbo's answer, I think that we can have the explicit solution of his/her equation $(2)$.

The equation to be solved being

$$u \sqrt{1 - \frac{(\beta - u)^2}{(\beta + 1)^2}} + \frac{\beta - u}{\beta + 1} \sqrt{1 - u^2} - 1 =0$$

let $z=\frac{\beta - u}{\beta + 1}$ to make
$$z\sqrt{1-u^2} +u \sqrt{1-z^2}-1=0 \implies z=\sqrt{1-u^2}$$ from which
$$\beta=\frac{\sqrt{1-u^2}+u}{1-\sqrt{1-u^2}}\implies \color{red}{u=\frac{\beta+ \sqrt{2(1+\beta) ^3} }{(1+\beta) ^2+1}}$$

Comment: Thank you, and thanks to @Glärbo for pointing out that no solution exists for $\beta<1$

Answer (score 0):

If I understood OP correctly, the function whose zeros we are looking for is
$$f(\alpha, N, u) = u \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{\alpha - N - u}{\alpha - N + 1}\right)^2} + \left(\frac{\alpha - N - u}{\alpha - N + 1}\right) \sqrt{1 - u^2} - 1 = 0 \tag{1a}\label{G1a}$$
where
$$-1 \le u \le +1 \tag{1b}\label{G1b}$$
because $\phi = \sin^{-1} u$.

We can simplify the function by using $\beta = \alpha - N$:
$$f(\beta, u) = u \sqrt{1 - \frac{(\beta - u)^2}{(\beta + 1)^2}} + \frac{\beta - u}{\beta + 1} \sqrt{1 - u^2} - 1 = 0 \tag{2}\label{G2}$$
Plotting $f(\beta, u)$ for $-1 \le u \le 1$ for a number of different $\beta$ shows that there are no zeros for $\beta \lt 1$.  $f(1, 1) = 0$, so for $\beta = 1$, there is a solution $u = 1$.  For $\beta \gt 1$, there is a solution $0 \le u \lt 1$.

The partial derivative of $f(\beta, u)$ with respect to $u$ is
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f(\beta, u)}{\partial u} = & - \frac{\sqrt{1 - u^2}}{\beta + 1} - \frac{(\beta - u) u}{(\beta + 1)\sqrt{1 - u^2}} \\
~ & + \frac{(\beta - u) u}{(\beta + 1)^2 \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{\beta-u}{\beta+1}\right)^2}} + \sqrt{1 - \left(\frac{\beta-u}{\beta+1}\right)^2} \\
\end{aligned} \tag{2b}\label{G2b}$$
and this can be used with the numerical search for a solution $u$, since the derivative is also zero at $f(\beta, u) = 0$, and has different signs around it.  Essentially, a binary search between $u = 0$ and $u = 1$ should find the solution at arbitrary precision.

Here is a Python implementation for finding the solutions $\alpha - N = \beta \gt 1$ (i.e. at least two unit squares):

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from math import sqrt
from sys import argv, stderr, exit

def f(beta, u):
    t = (beta - u) / (beta + 1)
    return u*sqrt(1-t*t) + t*sqrt(1-u*u) - 1

def df(beta, u):
    t = (beta - u) / (beta + 1)
    r = sqrt(1 - t*t)
    return (beta - u) * u / ((beta + 1)*(beta + 1)*r) + r - sqrt(1 - u*u) / (beta + 1) - (beta - u)*u / ((beta + 1)*sqrt(1 - u*u))

def find_u(beta):
    umin = 0
    dfmin = df(beta, umin)

    umax = 0.999999999
    dfmax = df(beta, umax)

    if dfmin <= 0 or dfmax >= 0:
        raise ValueError("df(0) = %.9f, df(1) = %.9f, so cannot use binary search to find a solution." % (dfmin, dfmax))

    while True:

        u = 0.5*umin + 0.5*umax
        if u == umin or u == umax:
            return u

        d = df(beta, u)

        if d < 0:
            umax = u
        elif d > 0:
            umin = u
        else:
            return u

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(argv) < 2 or argv[1] == "-h" or argv[1] == "--help":
        if len(argv) < 1 or len(argv[0]) < 1:
            argv0 = "(this)"
        else:
            argv0 = argv[0]
        stderr.write("\n")
        stderr.write("Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n" % argv0)
        stderr.write("       %s beta [ beta ... ]\n" % argv0)
        stderr.write("\n")
        stderr.write("This program uses a binary search to find solutions\n")
        stderr.write("    u*sqrt(1 - ((beta-u)/(beta+1))**2) + (beta-u)/(beta+1)*sqrt(1 - u**2) = 1\n")
        stderr.write("for 0 <= u <= 1.\n")
        stderr.write("\n")
        exit(0)

    for arg in argv[1:]:
        beta = float(arg)
        u = find_u(beta)
        print("For beta=%.16f and u=%.16f, f(beta,u)=%.16f" % (beta, u, f(beta,u)))
```

Running `python3 solve.py 2` this finds the solution for $\beta = 2$, $u \approx 0.9348469228349534$ (which corresponds to angle $\phi \approx 69.203^\circ$), where $f(\beta, u) = 0$.

Here are some tabulated solutions:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\beta & u & \phi \\
\hline
2 & 0.9348469228349534 & 69.203^\circ \\
3 & 0.8419828528814566 & 57.350^\circ \\
4 & 0.7619764731093037 & 49.639^\circ \\
5 & 0.6968813429953116 & 44.177^\circ \\
6 & 0.6438320341483518 & 40.078^\circ \\
7 & 0.5999999999999999 & 36.870^\circ \\
8 & 0.5632166607813849 & 34.279^\circ \\
9 & 0.5318946490098593 & 32.134^\circ \\
10 & 0.5048735521152274 & 30.323^\circ \\
20 & 0.3531573634990158 & 20.681^\circ \\
50 & 0.2171693896450677 & 12.543^\circ \\
100 & 0.1505077152282627 & 8.656^\circ \\
200 & 0.1046987146380977 & 6.010^\circ \\
500 & 0.0651741666398147 & 3.737^\circ \\
1000 & 0.0456969730170546 & 2.619^\circ \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Hi @Glärbo. In this example $u$ is a side length, so it's actually bounded below by 0. While this doesn't contradict your answer, just thought I'd point it out. Also, the problem here mainly deals with situations where $\beta$ is a mixed number (I should probably add that); this is considered the "interesting" case because if $\beta$ is a whole number, then we can directly stack unit squares into the whole integer area, without slanting the rectangles.